# Custom UITableViewCell on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib, iphone-6

I have a question for you. I'm using a custom UITableViewCell for my app, designed in a .xib file.

Everything work fine on my iPhone 5, but on iPhone 6, the layout of the cell is not correct.

Here a screenshot on iPhone 5 : [image: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/40/1411950368-ios-simulator-screen-shot-29-sept-2014-02-25-48.png]

Here on iPhone 6 : [image: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/40/1411950234-ios-simulator-screen-shot-29-sept-2014-02-22-41.png]

Do you have an idea on how to fix this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't add more than 2 links, so there is my .xib file : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/40/1411950233-capture-d-ecran-2014-09-29-a-02-22-13.png

Comment: What are the constraints? You're probably aligning to either the left (leading) side of the cell or the right (trailing) side of the label. You need to align trailing of Image view to trailing of cell.

Comment: Obviously, they are different size screens, and your code is not adapting.

Comment: auto layout (contraints) may be the best solution for this